# .net core enables custom middleware to affect route matching

Tags: asp.net

I am using .net core 2.2 to write a web api project, I have defined an api to log out, using the [HttpGet] attribute, which works fine. However, when I try to enable a custom middleware, the logout api cannot be matched, always returning 404.
I am not sure if the custom middleware is causing the problem.

```
logout api
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class SysUserController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Logout(string sysUserId)
        {
           some code...
        }
    }
```

```
custome middleware
public class TokenMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public TokenMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var token = httpContext.Request.Headers["X-Token"].ToString();
        if (token == "xxxxx")
        {
            return _next(httpContext);
        }

        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            message = "error message"
        }));
    }
}
```

```
startup
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            ...

            app.MapWhen((httpContext) => httpContext.Request.Path.ToString().ToLower() != "/api/sysuser/login",
                (obj) => obj.UseTokenMiddleware());
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Comment: When I changed `app.MapWhen` to `app.UseWhen` solved the problem

Comment: You don't need to change that, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good, just change in `Configure` method to this:

```
app.MapWhen((httpContext) => httpContext.Request.Path.ToString().ToLower() != "/api/sysuser/login",
            (obj) => obj.UseMiddleware<TokenMiddleware>());
        app.UseMvc();
```

Tested and it works

Comment: For ASP .NET Core 3.0+ I suggest using `app.UseWhen` which doesn't branch (actually it does but rejoins) the pipeline and copes well with endpoint routing.